# Type conversion: Convert type of Object with uniformly typed fields to Array type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Say I want to convert an the type of an object whose fields are uniformly typed, as string for example:

```js
// index.d.ts

const event = {
 RAIN: "RAIN",
 SUN: "SUN",
 CLOUDY: "CLOUDY",
}

// I can only use this
export type eventType = (typeof event)[keyof typeof event]
```

How would I go about converting that `eventType` to the Array of strings type ?

EDIT : I should have added that I don't control the `event`type, it's from a third party

Comment: Why not `enum`?

Comment: @Dimava Because I don't control the `event` type, it's from a third party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent the compiler from extending the type of values to `string`:

```
const events = {
 RAIN: "RAIN",
 SUN: "SUN",
 CLOUDY: "CLOUDY",
} as const

// type EventType = {
//     readonly RAIN: "RAIN";
//     readonly SUN: "SUN";
//     readonly CLOUDY: "CLOUDY";
// }
type EventType = typeof events
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKEYF4YG8BQMBKAggJIByAXDAERFlUA0eAygKoXWukN4DCAMgHkWAEQCalKvyFjuAXxgBDNKEhQcOAPQaYUAJ4AHODACiSFABUDRzLi0x79gE5wFAE3AAbXQRLsavqgBuTW0HGGc3T29OCU4gkLDwl3cwLxgpEXFqDJlgu1kcPUMTMyhLYswiuBAAM3hSiCA)

### Update

Since the object is coming from a third party I can't be manipulated, the only approach I could think of is to create another object that satisfies the original one and const assert it:

```
const myEvents ={
  RAIN: 'RAIN',
  SUN: 'SUN',
  CLOUDY: 'CLOUDY'
} as const satisfies typeof events;

type EventType = typeof myEvents
```

Comment: Thanks ! I should have added that I don't control the initial type, it's from a third party so I can't use `const`

Comment: @cassepipe which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: The latest one, 5.1.3

Comment: I don't think it is going to be possible, but I can suggest an alternative to creating a duplicate object that actually satisfies the original object. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKEYF4YG8BQMYBKAggJIByAXDAOTHnUA0eMAygKqU3tmPMDCAGQDybACIBNKtUEiJvAL4BuHDlCRYAWwCeAUSQo06XPjqdapHk3zcp3XvhljJNR3JzyYAQzRroMCJ5QAJYQAGZBcGhQWgAOcCCh8PqoyjjRcTB6yFAAKrFwGDDp8YnaWQZAA). Does it work for you?

Comment: Actually that does not work, sorry for moving the goalpost but I only have access to the type of the third party object (I edited my  question to reflect that)
I have tried removing the `typeof Object` after the `satisfies` and replaced it with the type but that does not work

Comment: In that you will have to specify keys manually. `satisfies Record<string, EventType>`

Comment: That does work although I can't pretend to understand why.
The string are indeed in sync with the string of the original fields, I can however name the fields however I like that does not seem to matter. I guess this has to do with how the type is exported in the first place ?

Comment: `EventType` is `string`, and it should be used as a type for the values, not for the whole object. Since, we don't have access to the keys we will manually say that `myEvents` satisfies `Record<string, EventType>`

Comment: But if it's just a `string` how is it able to keep in sync with the string of the original object ?

Comment: It can't... You should definitely try to get the access to keys at least

Answer (score 1):

```
const event1 = {
    RAIN: "RAIN",
    SUN: "SUN",
    CLOUDY: "CLOUDY",
}
type EventType = typeof event1
// type EventType = {
//     RAIN: string;
//     SUN: string;
//     CLOUDY: string;
// }
const keys1 = Object.keys(event1) as (keyof typeof event1)[]
// const keys1: ("RAIN" | "SUN" | "CLOUDY")[]

const event2 = {
    RAIN: "RAIN",
    SUN: "SUN",
    CLOUDY: "CLOUDY",
} as const
type EventType2 = typeof event2
// type EventType2 = {
//     readonly RAIN: "RAIN";
//     readonly SUN: "SUN";
//     readonly CLOUDY: "CLOUDY";
// }
type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T];
const values2 = Object.values(event3) as ValuesOf<typeof event2>[];
// const values2: ("RAIN" | "SUN" | "CLOUDY")[]

enum event3 {    
    RAIN = "RAIN",
    SUN = "SUN",
    CLOUDY = "CLOUDY",
}
// const event3 = {
//     RAIN: "RAIN",
//     SUN: "SUN",
//     CLOUDY: "CLOUDY",
// }
type EventType3 = event3
// ~= type EventType3 = "RAIN" | "SUN" | "CLOUDY"
// ~= type EventType3 = event3.RAIN | event3.SUN | event3.CLOUDY
const values3 = Object.values(event3) as event3[]
```